# Is generating API from codegen a good practice?

Tags: api-design, swagger-codegen

Im writing a new set of APIs mostly in golang and traditionally we have been writing the API and generating the swagger specs for it. However, I bumped into swagger codegen recently. I think it is a good way to manage APIs. This also ensures that our Swagger is always updated.
Do you think there are any disadvantages to using codegen to generate APIs? Can someone point me to articles for pros and cons?